# AppiumServiceBuilder does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method abstract void loadSystemProperties()'

Tags: server, appium, appium-android

I am unable to launch the appium server  via  programatically:

here the code snippet:

```
  @Test
    public void appiumBasic() throws MalformedURLException, URISyntaxException {
        AppiumServiceBuilder builder = new AppiumServiceBuilder().withAppiumJS(new File("C:\\Users\\spa6a5t\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\appium\\build\\lib\\main.js"))
                .usingDriverExecutable(new File("C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe"))
                .withIPAddress("http://0.0.0.0")
                .usingPort(4723)
                .withArgument(GeneralServerFlag.BASEPATH,"wd/hub");
                //.withArgument(GeneralServerFlag.LOCAL_TIMEZONE)
        AppiumDriverLocalService server = AppiumDriverLocalService.buildService(builder);
        server.start();

        System.out.println(server.getUrl());
        System.out.println(server.isRunning());
```

here the version details:
Appium version: Appium v1.22.3

I tried to update the appium server, still getting the same issue

Comment: what is your selenium and Appium version in project?

Comment: Selenium : 4.6.0
Appium v1.22.3 (server)
io.appium : 8.3.0